# How to remove grey shadow color below FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I am getting light grey color below the `FloatingActionButton` as shown in image. Any one know how to remove it. I tested it on Lollipop version.

**My xml code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

[image: Floating action button]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try set `elevation`:

`app:elevation="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you set an elevation and the fab element has not space enough to display the "shadow".

Then you can set the elevation as 0dp as suggested above, or set a margin like

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_build_white_36dp"
    android:id="@+id/build"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

In this way the "elevation-effect" will appear correctly