# Android button getting weird background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have two buttons with a custom background. However, there is a grey-coloured shadow showing behind the background on the bottom portion.

> I've already tried [How to remove grey shadow color below FloatingActionButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424635/how-to-remove-grey-shadow-color-below-floatingactionbutton) but it didn't work

This is my code:

**green_button_style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#62741A" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#8DA626" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**This is the button xml**

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/btnDimensions"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
  android:padding="10sp"
  android:textSize="18sp"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"
  android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Dimensions"
/>
```

[image]

**EDIT**

here's the entire layout code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mridulahuja.kudamm.activities.ComponentDetailsActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/light_green_background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.mridulahuja.kudamm.tools.SquareImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgComponent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:padding="5dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtComponentInfoTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.mridulahuja.kudamm.tools.ExpandableTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtComponentInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="component info"
                    android:textColor="#53524E"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">



                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDataAtAGlance"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:elevation="0dp"
                        android:text="Details"
                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDimensionsAtAGlance"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:padding="10sp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:elevation="0dp"
                        android:text="Dimensions"
                        />



            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>



            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDownloadPdfCatalogue"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    android:text="PDF Catalogue"
                    />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: care to explain the downvote ?

Comment: what is your parent layout background color. I think it's parent bg color.

Comment: Dont Worry about downvote here, some people are too smart to consider these as question , i just answered your question if that helps :)

Comment: @mrid Please upload  parent xml of Button

Comment: have you tried **style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"** property to btn..

Comment: @JamesMacca I've already tried that out but it didn't work. so it's not a duplicate

Comment: @mrid Fair enough! I have removed the duplicate comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding style to your button:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDimensions"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/green_button_style"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Dimensions"
    />
```

It will give the button with boderless background.

Comment: this gives the error: no resource found  for attribute 'style' in package android

Comment: sorking now, had accidently used `android:style` instead of just `style`. In my last app, I had used a similar styling but that didn't show this problem. Any idea why was that ?

Comment: @mrid It also works with android:style sometimes, but the proper way to put is to just use style. android never seize to amaze you :P

Answer (score 1):

set one more property in button

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null" or

 android:background="@null" or setting elevation
 app:elevation
```